# Volley Library return bitmap

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to use the library volley, but I'm in doubt.

The volley library has some function that simply returns a bitmap?

pseudocode:

```
Bitmap bmp = Volley.getImageURL (url);
```

Thank you

Comment: If in doubt, try it out.

Comment: I´m trying use library but I can't use library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it has such a functionality:
http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/volley-part-3-image-loader

Sample code:

```
String imageUrl = "http://some.server.com/image.png";
Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(new ImageRequest(imageUrl, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
        // Do something with loaded bitmap...
    }
}, 1024, 1024, null, null));
```

But there is better library for loading images from the Internet - [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Sample code:

```
String imageUrl = "http://some.server.com/image.png";  
// This request is synchronous, so it shouldn't be made from main thread
Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).get();
```

Comment: Please do not only post links. An answer should be self-contained.

Comment: Looks much better. :)

Comment: picasso is very good solution, but for sake of low size apps, try to use just one library for everything, can be done with volley.